# IRC Message format clarification

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, standards, protocols, irc

I have this message received from an IRC server

```
:shiplu!shiplu@example.com PRIVMSG &channel :bot: Poor baby!\r\n
```

Here `PRIVMSG` is command. The rest part at the right is `&channel :bot: Poor baby!`

Now what is the last parameter? `:bot: Poor baby!` or  `Poor baby!`

On the [RFC2810 Section 2.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#section-2.3.1) It written that

```
    nospcrlfcl =  %x01-09 / %x0B-0C / %x0E-1F / %x21-39 / %x3B-FF
                    ; any octet except NUL, CR, LF, " " and ":"
    middle     =  nospcrlfcl *( ":" / nospcrlfcl )
    trailing   =  *( ":" / " " / nospcrlfcl )
```

Now if `:bot: Poor baby!` is the last parameter how can it contain any colon? `nospcrlfcl` is defined not to contain any colon. If  `Poor baby!` is the last parameter how can `:bot:` become middle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trailing (last) parameter is flagged with a colon and may contain spaces. Middle parameters may not contain spaces, and may not start with a colon.

So &channel is a "middle" and `bot: Poor baby!` (without the leading colon) is "trailing".